# bootbox confirm dialog box, cancel button is not working

Tags: bootbox

I have a bootbox confirm dialog box. In that, I have some form validation.Validation working fine and as long as validation fails confirm dialog box still opens. But when I click on the cancel button, still it is asking for validation.

```
bootbox.confirm({ 
    closeButton: true,
    message: valid_result,
    size: 'large',
    title: 'Fill fields with related values',
     buttons    : {
     confirm : { label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Validate'}
    }, 

      callback: function () {                  
           var res =  getLinkupInformation(ids_string)
            if(res == true) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }

      }
  });
```

The validation part is working and if validation passed then only modal was closing. But when user click on the cancel button or close icon still it is asking validation. `When I remove return false in call back function in else part` then the `validation button is not working` and when `I click on the validate button confirmation dialog box was closing`.
Please guide me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The callback expects you to supply an argument, like so:

```
callback: function (result) {

}
```

If the user cancelled the dialog, either by clicking Cancel or the close (x) button, then `result` (or whatever you called your argument) will be the value `false`. You would use that value like this:

```
callback: function (result) {
    if(result) {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```

This is more or less covered [in the documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-confirm).